# Lenovo y70 70 touch - how to clean the heatsink?

Tags: overheating, thermal-paste, thermal-pads

I have a Lenovo y70 70 touch laptop, and I have a problem with CPU and GPU overheating. This is because I don't have that rubber on my heatsink anymore; I cleaned it. I have ordered stuff called cooling pads but it's about 0.01mm and it not helping at all. Can you help to figure out what it is on my heatsink and find what kind of pads I need to order from eBay or other online shop?

P.S. Lenovo costumer support doesn't tell me what is this and just gives me a link where I can buy a new heatsink.

It's the yellow stuff in this picture:

[image]